# Conversion int to char

Tags: c, ascii

I have some issues recently in C application. This application work fine in production but fail in local test.

My application :

- collect parameters in file for insert and extract some informations on database. (This parameter is use to determinate separator and some option in csv out file or log file)
- Use a bulk insert after create a .fmt file

And there is the problem. Before create the .fmt file, the application translate the separator in "Code page 850". It's not me that is created this part, but it's work fine in production. We use the separator '¤' and in return, this function i have the char 'Ì' instead of '¤'.

I deepened my research and i noticed that :

```
printf("\n%c", -49);  --> '¤' on my PC (Windows 7)

printf("\n%c", -49);  --> 'Ì' on VM    (Windows 2008 R2)
```

How the natural convertion is doing? With ASCII table, no?
How this results can be different?

This problem occurred one month ago, but work fine previously. We change some information like Language & Region and some Windows Registry.

can this have an impact on my problem?

Comment: There exists, as far as I know, no symbol table with negative indices.

Comment: If you do a hexdump on each file you wrote, do they show up as the same character? Your application may work differently depending on the locale. Make sure the locale is the same on both systems to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the -49 to an unsigned hexadecimal representation and print the entire word. Note that your printf is using `%c` if the actual character value being picked up by the platform (a single byte) is different, then the output is different. For example big endian and low endian. I think that you will see why the two platforms print different characters.

Answer (score 0):

> How the natural conversion is doing?

```
printf("%c%c", -49, 'X');
```

When the `int` `-49` or the `int` character constant `'X'` is passed to `printf()`, the format specifier `"%c"`expects an `int`.  So far so good.  `printf()` takes that value and converts it to an `unsigned char`.  So a -49 would print the same as code 256-49 or 207.

> With ASCII table, no?   How this results can be different?

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only defines codes 0 - 127.  Character code 207 will print different things, dependent on how that platform and settings handles codes 128 - 255.

> ... We change some information like Language & Region ... can this have an impact on my problem?

Oh yes.